# MongoTemplate project Object as List of one Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I'm using spring MongoTemplate and I have objects like below

**The main objects,**

```
{
    id: "001",
    name: "one",
    age: 12,
    hobby: "a"
}

{
    id: "001",
    name: "one",
    age: 12,
    hobby: "b"
}
```

**The projection result,**

```
{
    id: "001",
    name: "one",
    hobbyList: ["a", "b"]
}
```

This is the aggregate I'm using so far. It's not working and I don't have an idea how to combine those two objects. How can I fix this?

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(newAggregation(project("user.id","user.name")
    .and("hobby").as("hobbyList")), "User", User.class).getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group` and `project` operation to achieve this,

First we'll `group` id, name, age under `_id` attribute and push all common `hobbies` to `hobbyList` attribute.

Then use `project` is to pull out all the grouped result and exclude `_id`

```
newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group("id", "name", "age").push("hobby").as("hobbyList"), 
    Aggregation.project("_id.id", "_id.name", "_id.age", "hobbyList").andExclude("_id")
)
```